# How to fill a single Model Object with multiple chained URL requests Request Dependency?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, urlsession

I have a data model object that I have to fill with multiple network requests.

My model looks like this

```
struct CO2Data: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let totalCO2: Double
    let dailyAverage: Int
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateString: String
    let emissionStats: EmissionStats

let driveLog: String 
    // It is an ID to get the trip details

    let trip : Trip
    // This is what needs to be filled from the next URL request using driveLog


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case totalCO2 = "totCO2"
        case dateString = "stDt"
        case dailyAverage = "avg"
        case emissionStats = "emisStats"
        case drLogRefId = "drLogRefId"
        //Not having case trip here breaks the conformance to codable
        // and results in error
    }
}
```

```
struct Trip: Codable {
    let startTime: String
    let endTime: String
    let startLat: String
    let startLong: String
    let endLat: String
    let endLong: String
}
```

This is the flow of the network request and responses

1. request to get the CO2Data and decode it using JSONDecoder()
2. use the driveLog Property in the fetched CO2Data to make another network request to get the Trip object.
3. The result of the second network request should be added to the CO2Data object in the trip property.

How should I go about this. Is it even possible to store the Trip in CO2 data?

I am using the Combine & URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest) for this, but I can totally use plain old simple data task.
Are there known ways to handle request dependencies like this? 
I am not using any third party libraries and wish to stick with URLSession.

JSON Objects look like this

```
// for CO2Data
[
  {
    "stDt": "2019-11-17T16:00:00.000+0000",
    "totCO2": 50,
    "avg": 0,
    "emisStats": {
      "wea": 10,
      "aggDr": 10,
      "tfc": 10,
      "tirePress": 0,
      "ac": 10,
      "seatHeater": 10
    },
    "drLogRefId": "5dc20204199f752c7726a8f0"
  }
]

//for Trip
[
  {
    "id": "5dc20204199f752c7726a8f0",
    "startTime": "...",
    "startLat: "...",
    "startLong: "...",
    "endLat: "...",
    "endLong": "...",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve your goal. You need to make `Trip` optional during the first network call as you don't have data to set there. Make sure handle this properly during json decoding.

Then use `flatMap` to make the second network call. 
Use `zip` to wait for both requests to complete and pass result data to extension `CO2Data.init`.

Full Code where `fetchCO2TripData` will return `CO2Data` with `Trip` :

```
struct CO2Data: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    /// TODO: add other properties
    let driveLog: String
    let trip : Trip?
}

struct Trip: Codable {
    let startTime: String
    let endTime: String
    let startLat: String
    let startLong: String
    let endLat: String
    let endLong: String
}

func fetchCO2Data() -> AnyPublisher<CO2Data, Error> {
    /// TODO: Replace with actual network request
    Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func fetchTripData(by driveLog: String) -> AnyPublisher<Trip, Error> {
    /// TODO: Replace with actual network request
    Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func fetchCO2TripData() -> AnyPublisher<CO2Data, Error> {
    let co2Publisher = fetchCO2Data().share()
    let tripPublisher = co2Publisher.flatMap { fetchTripData(by: $0.driveLog) }

    return co2Publisher
        .zip(tripPublisher)
        .map { CO2Data(co2data: $0, trip: $1) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

extension CO2Data {
    init(co2data: CO2Data, trip: Trip) {
        self.driveLog = co2data.driveLog
        self.trip = trip
    }
}
```

P.S. I would rather recommend creating high-level model that will be composed of both network calls, to eliminate optional trip:

```
struct Model {
    let co2Data: CO2Data
    let trip: Trip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the surrounding data look either into

- Operations: You can specify other operations this operation is dependent on.
- DispatchGroup: With `DispatchGroup.enter()`, `DispatchGroup.leave()` and finally `DispatchGroup.notify()` you can also model dependencies of dispatched tasks you perform.

Good luck.